# Insight on how to arrive at this recursive BST solution

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

From Cracking the Coding Interview, this code creates a binary search tree with minimal height (balanced) given a sorted (in increasing order) array.

```
Node createMinimalBST(int arr[]) {
 return createMinimalBST(array, 0, array.length - 1);
}

Node createMinimalBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {
 if (end < start) {
  return null;
 }

 int mid = (start + end) / 2;
 Node n = new Node(arr[mid]);
 n.left = createMinimalBST(arr, start, mid - 1);
 n.right = createMinimalBST(arr, mid + 1, end);
 return n;
}
```

I follow this code completely, but I couldn't come up with this solution myself.

Specifically, after writing out the variable values on an example input, the trick seems to be that start should be <= end. That makes sure that we insert array values in the correct place as well as terminating null pointers. But I am really amazed at how someone managed to figure that out and use that to write this recursive function. Can anybody provide insight on how they would go about deriving this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this problem as follows. We need to build a BST. The most obvious way to construct it is first to choose the root node. How do we choose it? Well, we know that in BST all values in the left subtree are less than the root value and all nodes in the right subtree are greater than the root value. But we have another requirement - BST should be balanced and have minimum height. Intuitively, it means that the left subtree of the whole tree should be of the same size as the right subtree and their heights should not differ too much (usually, by not more than one). Now, how to choose the root value so that approximately half of the values are in the left subtree (less than the root value) and another half are in the right subtree (greater than the root value)? Sort all the values and pick the middle value to be the root value. Conviniently enough, we already have the values sorted. Now that we picked the root value, we need to construct the left subtree and the right subtree. How to do it? Observe, that these two problems are in fact the same problem we started with, so the logic we used there applies. Indeed, we have a sorted array (left half of the original array) and we need to construct a minimum-height balanced BST from it to make the whole tree a minimum-height balanced BST (analogously, for the right half). Consider the left half of the original array and pick its middle value to be the root of the left subtree (the right subtree is constructed in the similar way). Now we see the pattern and can proceed recursively making sure that we return `null` once the array in the recursive call becomes empty (the minimum-height balanced BST constructed from the empty array is just a null pointer).